# How to get the label name as value for the selected/checked checkboxes in Django template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, django-templates

In django template , i have a modal which pops up on click of a span.

```
 <div class="modal-body">
     <form action="#">
         <fieldset>
             <legend>Please Select Your Option</legend>
                 <p><label style="font-size:15px;"><input type="checkbox" style="margin-right:5px;" id="selectAll"/>Select All</label></p>
              <div id="options">                  
                    {% for data in allData %}
   <p><label style="font-size:15px;" for={{data}}><input type="checkbox" style="margin-right:5px;" value={{data}}/>{{option}}</label></p>
             {% endfor %}
        <div>
         </fieldset>
     </form>
</div>
```

I saw many examples and get to know that using ids i can access the value property of each checkbox. but i am really confused in this case where the  no of checkboxes are dynamic.

I want to access the label name as the value . Any help?

Edit :

```
var allVals = [];
$('#options :checked').each(function() {
       allVals.push($(this).val());
});
console.log(allVals);
```

I used this jquery code to get the values, but it doesnot returns the complete value, as i have done in the code (put the label name in value property).

Eg. If the option says:

```
a,b,c,d
```

it returns the array having [a].

Comment: do you want the label text ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){


        // for delete row
        $('#container').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function () {
            alert($(this).closest('label').text());
        });

        $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
            iCounter=$('#container p').siblings().length + 1
            $('#container').append('<p><label style="font-size:15px;" for="test1"><input type="checkbox" style="margin-right:5px;" value="test1"/>sample' + iCounter + '</label></p>');

        });



    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btnAdd">Add Data</button>
    <div class="modal-body">
     <form action="#">
         <fieldset>
             <legend>Please Select Your Option</legend>
                 <p><label style="font-size:15px;"><input type="checkbox" style="margin-right:5px;" id="selectAll"/>Select All</label></p>
             <div id="container">

             <p><label style="font-size:15px;" for="test1"><input type="checkbox" style="margin-right:5px;" value="test1"/>sample</label></p>

            </div>
         </fieldset>
     </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The no. of checkboxes are in a loop, ie are dynamic.